# "Psycopg2.error column doesn't exist" error when trying to write injection-safe PostgreSQL query on Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm writing a function to dynamically create insert/update/select queries for PostgreSQL database using psycopg2 library.

I've been trying to write the function injection-safe according to the recommendations provided by [psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html) - using `sql.Sql` method to compose the query correctly. All the parameters (table name, columns to insert, the values) are passed dynamically to the function:

```py
def insert(table, columns: list, values: list):

    query = sql.SQL('INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({});').format(
                    sql.Identifier(table),
                    sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, columns)),
                    sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, values))
                   )
    cursor = foo_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
```

When I'm trying to test the function:

```py
insert('test_table', ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], ['1', '2', '3'])
```

I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "1" does not exist
LINE 1: ...e" ("col1", "col2", "col3") VALUES ("1", "2", ...
```

I don't undesrtand the error since technically it is not even a column, it is a value to be inserted.

I thought the query was composed incorrectly but the result of `print(query.as_string(foo_connection))` shows that it seems to be correct:

```
INSERT INTO "test_table" ("col1", "col2", "col3") VALUES ("1", "2", "3");
```

The official documentation does not cover that situation. Googling did not give me the answers either.

So, the question are:

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. How to make this code work?

Comment: Are you able to check your postgres database table columns? `UndefinedColumn: column "1" does not exist` seems to suggest that you are trying to insert a value into a column named "1", which isn't an actual column in your table.

Comment: The error suggests that I'm trying to insert a column named "1" but it is the value to be inserted according to the query print mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Laurenz says, in psycopg2 documentation, it's written:

> Identifiers usually represent names of database objects, such as tables or fields.

I also saw for Literals objects:

> representing an SQL value to include in a query.

Maybe you can try replacing Identifiers by Literals when you are formatting your queries:

```
query = sql.SQL('INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({});').format(
                sql.Identifier(table),
                sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, columns)),
                sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Literals, values))
               )
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help, sir!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's your quotations of your query. Maybe try to use doubles on the outside:

```
def insert(table, columns: list, values: list):

    query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({});").format(
                    sql.Identifier(table),
                    sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Identifier, columns)),
                    sql.SQL(', ').join(map(sql.Literlas, values))
                   )
    cursor = foo_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you format the value constants as `sql.Identifier`.

This causes them to be quoted with double instead of single quotes, so PostgreSQL considers them table columns. Hence the error message.

The best thing would be to use `%s` placeholders for the literals and pass them as a second argument to `execute()`.

Comment: Is there any way to make `sql.Identifier` create single quotes? Or should I compose the query in a completely different manner then?

Comment: Use parameters, as indicated in the extended answer.